# Unable to open Anaconda command prompt or any notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, windows-10, command-prompt

Anaconda is not responding for any environment whenever I try to open a command prompt or any other application such as jupyter-notebook. I have installed Anaconda's latest available version for Windows 10. This is the 3rd time I have reinstalled the software thinking that the outcome might change but to no avail. I am able to open the command prompt from the Environments option but still, this option does not work for the jupyter-notebook. However, I am able to open the jupyter-notebook from the command prompt but the kernel dies every other minute. Please guide and help me if you can.

Comment: This is not reproducible for me. What exactly did you do wrong with the Anaconda installation?

Comment: I did not face any trouble with the installation. But launching Anaconda when I try to open a command prompt or jupyter-notebook(after installation) in any environment, I get no response.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.